# How can I click the Attach File button in Gmail with Python + Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try to click on the button that appears in gmail with selenium, but I have not been able to click on it.
[image]

This is the code I have:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.aaA').send_keys(r"C:\Users\micomputer\Desktop\perritos\dog.png")
```

When running it, I get an error that the button cannot be found. Somebody can help me? Thank you in advance for your support. Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a file with Selenium by sending the uploading file path, you should use this element locator `//input[@type="file"]`
So instead of

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.aaA').send_keys(r"C:\Users\micomputer\Desktop\perritos\dog.png")
```

Please try

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').send_keys(r"C:\Users\micomputer\Desktop\perritos\dog.png")
```

Comment: Yep, works!, thanks very much

Comment: I know :) This is how it works on most web pages :)

Comment: Add a new post: How can I click the close button in Gmail with Python + Selenium?